# Issues setting Supplemental Files to display in new window as opposed to 'modal' window

Tags: docusignapi

We have recently changed our system to include a supplemental document within our DocuSign envelope (previously we only had a single document in each envelope).

During testing it became clear that after clicking on the ‘view’ button next to the supplemental document, the majority of our users where unable to figure out how to then close the supplemental document in order to return to the main contract.

ie: they couldn’t figure out that they needed to click the ‘x’ in the top right corner. Upon questioning it became clear they couldn't appreciate that the supplemental document was being displayed as a modal window overlaying the form.

[image: image: the modal window covers the entire form and needs to be dismissed by clicking the 'x']

As a result we decided to set the supplemental file to display in a new browser window instead of a modal dialog.

The documentation (found under “envelopeDocument”) on https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/list/ suggests this can be done by simply changing the “display” parameter from “**modal**” to “**download**”

However when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
 "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
 "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. The value 'download' for display, is invalid for document with id= 2"
}
```

Does anyone know if this is the right approach? Is there something else I need to do in order to get this to work?

Comment: Please edit your question: ADD the API trace of your API call showing your request and the error response. Please elide personal information from the trace. How to trace: https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

Comment: I could replicate the issue, let me check with our Product team to validate it, if the issue is in documentation or in API call. But it would be great if you could share your JSON request call in your post as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try using below, it should open the supplemental doc in a new browser window

```
"display": "collapsible"
```

`download` value is not supported.